# SQL Loader INFILE with file in a different path

Tags: sh, sql-loader

I have a SQL Loader Control File in the directory `/opt/TEST/app/ITT/script/ctl/`.

The input file is in the directory `/opt/TEST/app/ITT/in/`.

The SQL Loader Control File can't stay in the same directory of the input file, so I must take it putting the right directory.

Is it correct to write this code in the control file?

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/opt/TEST/app/ITT/in/FILE1.ready'
BADFILE '/opt/TEST/app/ITT/in/FILE1.bad'
DISCARDFILE '/opt/TEST/app/ITT/in/FILE1.dsc'
```

I would prefer to do something easier without writing the whole directory, but just to got back from `/ctl/` to `/ITT/` and then to enter in the `/in/` directory but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `'./opt/TEST/app/ITT/in/FILE1.ready'` is not the same as `'/opt/TEST/app/ITT/in/FILE1.ready'`. The last one is an absolute path, the first one is relative to the current directory (and that means it depends on the current directory; an absolute path doesn't depend on anything).

Comment: @axiac sorry it was a mistake, i corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /u01/*/*/tmp/*_OCI/*.csv | while read INFILE
do
echo load data                                  >  /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo infile "'$INFILE'"                         >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo append into table cons_sqldata             >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo fields terminated by "','"                 >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo '('db_name,                                >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo cons_grp,                                  >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo sql_count,                                 >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo sql_execs')'                               >> /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
chmod 755 /u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo
echo invoking the sql*loader
echo using table $INFILE
sqlldr userid=test/test#123@test_f control=/u01/tmp/temp_ctl.ctl
echo "****************************************************************"
done
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation, the INFILE path has to be surrounded by single qotes:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1008018

Example:

```
INFILE 'c:/topdir/subdir/datafile.dat'
```